# How do I get a custom resolution?

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, 20.04

I am trying to make a Ubuntu VM and the resolution was not right, so I went online and could not find anything that works, it always gives me some errors. If someone could tell me how to do it for the newest version that would be a big help, thanks.

Comment: Install Guest Additions to VM.

Answer (score 0):

For the common resolution you should use the default "Displays" tools

For custom reslution have a look at `xrandr`

Here is a full guide: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/